# Search CSV using values from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, google-admin-sdk

I have a CSV that has two Columns a Computer and an action I also have another CSV that has 3 Columns Computer Identifier Serial Number and Device ID.

I want to take CSV1 and take Computer column and search for those values in CSV2 and see if its the computer identifier or serial and give me the matching device ID so I can run another function against that.

So CSV 1

| Computer | Action |
| --- | --- |
| CB12345 | Lock |
| 574638 | Unlock |

Will Search through for where the computer value is in CSV 2

| DeviceID | CB Number | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57687348 | CB12345 | 674Z2X3 |
| 34554345 | CB65487 | 474Z2X3 |
| 54868323 | CB45789 | 574Z2X3 |
| 15593235 | CB65976 | 974Z2X3 |
| 37593236 | CB35466 | 074Z2X3 |

Once it finds the value whether it be a CB number or serial it will grab its corresponding Device ID so I can use that in another function.

This is what I had so far but I am not sure how to do it so I can use both CSVs

````
$yesterday = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
$date = get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$CB = import-csv -Path "\\Scripts\GAM test\CBs" 
$GAM = import-csv -Path "\\Scripts\GAM\CSV\$yesterday-GAMprintCROSbasic.csv"

```  
<# foreach ($record in $CB)
    {
    if ($record.action = "Unlock")
        {
        $DeviceID = $record.deviceID
        $DeviceAsset = $record.asset

        E:\gam\gam.exe update cros $DeviceID action enable
            Write-Output "$deviceID is being disabled. $deviceasset"
        Start-Sleep 10 #>
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: `if ($record.action = "Unlock")`  needs to be `if ($record.action -eq "Unlock")`  in PowerShell

Comment: If you are able I would consider using a tool that can do the join between CSV1 and CSV2, and run the shell script on the CSV3 results; otherwise each time you do a run, your script will need to load CSV2 into ram, which if CSV2 is massive could get time consuming and expensive on automating a high turnover of the CSV1 file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the current computer record to find a matching **CB Number** or **Serial** from the second CSV, you can use a `where` statement for that.

Here is a trimmed down example demonstrating that.

```
# CSV #1 - Computer / Action
$CB = import-csv -Path "\\Scripts\GAM test\CBs" 
# CSV #2 - DeviceID / CB Number /Serial
$GAM = import-csv -Path "\\Scripts\GAM\CSV\$yesterday-GAMprintCROSbasic.csv"

foreach ($record in $CB) {
    if ($record.action -eq "Unlock") {
        # Select  matching value 
        $GamRecord = $Gam | Where { $_.'CB Number' -eq $Record.Computer -or $_.'Serial' -eq $Record.Computer } | Select -First 1
        if ($null -eq $GamRecord) {
            Write-Warning "No match for: $($record.Computer)"
            Continue
        }

        $Serial = $GamRecord.Serial    


 
        # $GamRecord.'CB NUmber'
        # $GamRecord.DeviceID

    }

}
```

Once you have the `$GamRecord`, which is the first record that correlated with `$Record.Computer` either in its **CB Number** or **Serial**, you can access all the properties from both CSVS through their respective variable.

```
$record.Computer # Is a match to either $GamRecord.'CB Number' or $GamRecord.Serial
$record.Action
$GamRecord.'CB Number'
$GamRecord.DeviceId
$GamRecord.Serial
```

Note that I left a  `if ($null -eq $GamRecord) {` as you might want to do something specific in the event **Computer** from the first CSV do not correspond to any **CB Number** or **Serial** in CSV2.

Also note the use of `-eq` when doing a comparison in the **if** statements.
In your initial sample, as pointed out by one of the commenter, you used `if ($record.action = "Unlock")`, which is incorrect. `=` is only used to assign a value  to a variable, not as a comparison operator. For the latter, `-eq` is used.